# Once Appended unable to change .CSS Position

Tags: jquery, css, cookies, position, append

I am appending some code from one document to another. Once the code has been appended i try to set the position of the new appended item using JQuery drag and drop. When i drag and drop the element the position is stored in an array and saved in a cookie. When the page is refreshed i retrieve the cookie and set the position from the cookie.

Everything seems to be working but the last part when i refresh the page the element doesn't revert to the saved position.

Here is the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    checkApps();
    checkpositions();
});

function checkpositions() {
    if ($.cookie('PosApps')){
        var Poscookie = $.cookie('PosApps');
        var Pos = JSON.parse(Poscookie);

        $("#TimenDate").css({top:Pos[0].top, left:Pos[0].left});
        $("#User").css({top:Pos[1].top, left:Pos[1].left});
        $("#Weather").css({top:Pos[2].top, left:Pos[2].left});
        $("#facebooka1thd").css({top:Pos[3].top, left:Pos[3].left});
    };
};

function getFacebook() {
    var appname = "facebooka1thd";
    $.get("apps/"+appname+"/"+appname+".html", function(data){
        $('.AppList').append(data);
        $.cookie(appname, 1, { expires : 365 });
    });
};

function dragEnable() {
    $( ".AppSettings" ).show();
    $( "#dialog-settings" ).dialog( "close" );
    newAppDraggable();
    $( "#User .AppSettings" ).dblclick(function() {
        dragDisable();
    });
};

function newAppDraggable() {
    $('.App').draggable({
        handle: ".AppSettings",
        containment: "#AppBox",
        grid: [ 10, 10 ],
        stack: ".App"
    });
};

$(function() {
    $('.AppList').droppable({
        accept: ".App",
        tolerance: 'fit',
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            getAppPositions();
        }
    }); 
});

function getAppPositions() {
    var apps = $(".App"),
    positions = [];

    $.each(apps, function (index, app) {
        var positionInfo = $(app).position();

        positions.push(positionInfo);
    });
    var setPositions = JSON.stringify(positions);

    $.cookie("PosApps", setPositions, { expires : 365 });
};

function checkApps() {
    if ($.cookie('facebooka1thd')) {
        getFacebook();
    };
};
```

The 'facebooka1thd' document:

```
<style>
.facebooka1thd {background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #133783 0px, #102E6D 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 #133783;}
.AppHeadfacebooka1thd img {
    height:24px;
    width:24px;
    padding:0;
    margin:1px 0 1px 0;
    float:left;
}
.AppHeadfacebooka1thd h1 {
    height:26px;
    padding:2px 0 2px 0;
    margin:0;
    font:bold 15px/22px 'Arial Narrow',Arial,Sans-Serif;
    float:left;
}
</style>
<div id="facebooka1thd" class="facebooka1thd App Size170x290 Optional">
    <div class="AppHeadfacebooka1thd">
        <img src="apps/facebooka1thd/Facebook.png" alt="Facebook"></img>
        <h1>Your News Feed<h1>
    </div>

    <div class="AppSettings"></div>
</div>
```

The Document it gets appended to:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

<!-- JQuery --->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<!-- App Resorces --->
    <script src='javascript/jquery.cookie.js'></script>

<!-- Main Scripts --->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/scripts.js"></script>

<!-- Main Styles --->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheets/styles.css" />

</head>
<body id="FullScreen">

    <section id="AppBox">
        <div class="AppList"></div>
    </section>
```

I don't know why it won't work..

Comment: Can only assume that recreating the page from the cookie data doesn't result in exactly the same state. Could be HTML or CSS or both. You simply have to track down the differences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope i'm understanding this correctly but i think you'll have to call `checkpositions()` from inside your `getFacebook()` `$.get` callback after `$('.AppList').append(data);`

The way it is now, `checkApps()` and `checkpositions()` get called at the same time. But `checkposition()` has to execute after the new elements get created.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! What you suggested works perfectly. I had tried to move the call around but i never thought to put it in that specific position.

Comment: Well spotted. It's an async issue.

Comment: By returning a promise from `getFacebook()` via `checkApps()`, you can use `checkApps().then(checkpositions);`, which is cleaner. (It's very slightly more complicated because the cookie may not be set but still reasonably trivial).

Answer (score 0):

jQuery adds more than coordinates for the elements to be at arbitrary positions, either `position:relative` or `position:absolute`. You need to make the elements draggable before being able to set their coordinates.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but i do make the elements draggable and i even stated that, that part of the code was working fine. Thanks though